# SSIS to import data from excel into multiple tables

Tags: ssis

I have an Excel sheet (input) where each row needs to be saved in one of three SQL server tables based on the Record type (column 1) of the row.

Example:

- If the Record type is `EMP`, the whole row should go to the `Employee` table.
- If the Record type is `CUS`, the whole row should go to the `Customer` table

I am trying to use a multicast and not sure how to split the data from multicast to the destination table. Do I need any other control in between?

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: And since after nearly 5 years I had no idea what [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) meant, I provideth a link

Comment: Never herard of MCVE.I am trying to use a multicast and not sure how to split the data from multicast to the destination table.Do I need any other control in between?

Comment: First, provide sameple of the data in the spreadsheet. It makes a difference if the structure of each type of recordtype is the same or is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *Conditional Split Component* sounds like just want you need. A Conditional Split uses expressions you define to route each input row to **one** output. In your case, your Conditional Split would define three outputs, each of which would be attached to a SQL destination.

In comparison, the *Multicast Component* you're currently using sends each input row to **all** outputs. This component would be useful if you were trying to save a copy of each row to *all* three SQL destinations.

Comment: Yes, I used Conditional Split between multicast and the destination table. it worked and I thought I can post as answer.But I just saw that Ben Gribaudo suggested the same. So I guess I will accept that as answer.

Comment: Are you using the Multicast to allow other processing of the data? That component shouldn't be necessary if the only processing needed is to route rows from the spreadsheet between the three destinations.

Comment: I was just trying to use conditional Split to define three outputs.But it gives only two output as maximum(?) and one error output.I could not get the 3rdoutput. or should I use with multicast.

Comment: Okay.I was not sure how to divide it based on three condition.I think this link may get  answer https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-conditional-split/   Thanks for your help, Ben.